# Loop over li items and set variables to do different things in each li item

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to find every specific LI element on a page, look through it for particular class, pull out that class, change it a bit and then set their values as variables.

There are up to 12 li items on a page at one time, and each have different values of the 'was' price. I want to grab that 'was' price and use within that li element only.

Here is what I have so far:

**js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#productList ul.gridStyle li").each(function () {

        var wasPriceMinusWasRemoval = jQuery('#productList p.was').text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
        var wasPrice = wasPriceMinusWasRemoval.replace("Was ", "");
        console.log(wasPrice); // ==> "149.99Was 119.99" (should be just 149.99)
        // generate a specific tag using .attr() dependent on 
        // wasPrice value inside this li element
    });
});
```

Question is, where to go from here? Use of index?

Comment: Use `this`, What's the problem?

Comment: Wasn't sure @Satpal, hence the question. Still very much someone who is learning the ropes. 'This' is a tricky concept to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `this` reference inside the `.each()` function,

```
var wasPriceMinusWasRemoval = jQuery('p.was',this).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
```